# How to filter values in dictionary of type [Type: [Type]]()

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift4

I have a dictionary with multiple values and I want to filter through it for nil values. The type of dictionary is:

```
var dic = [Int: [String]]()
```

The dictionary is:

```
var dic = [218: ["A", "B", "C",""],216: ["Q", "", "W",""]]

//remove the empty values
let filter = dic.filter({ !$0.value.isEmpty})
print(filter)
```

It returns the same dictionary values with the nil values, which supposed to be removed.

Comment: The value `["Q", "", "W",""]` is not empty, and strictly spoken an empty string is not a `nil` value

Comment: I think it is because I've tried the same filter on
 let dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]
let filter = dic.filter({ !$0.value.isEmpty})
print(filter) // Prints ["a": "1", "b": "2", "d": "3"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to filter the inner array from `""` which is not `nil` but represents an empty string You need

```
let filter = dic.mapValues { $0.filter { $0 != "" } }
```